# Makefile to build Hugo in another directory not working

Tags: macos, makefile, hugo

I have a Makefile located in the root directory and I have a Hugo install within that directory because it needs to be that way for my purposes.  When I run my Makefile to cd into the Hugo directory and build, it doesn't do it properly.  It will create the public folder, but it doesn't build completely

```
build:
    cd /Users/me/Sites/mysite/webroot/hugosite & hugo
```

Outcome:

```
                   | EN  
+------------------+----+
  Pages            |  3  
  Paginator pages  |  0  
  Non-page files   |  0  
  Static files     |  0  
  Processed images |  0  
  Aliases          |  0  
  Sitemaps         |  1  
  Cleaned          |  0
```

Expected Outcome (when I do it manually):

```
                   | EN   
+------------------+-----+
  Pages            |  31  
  Paginator pages  |   0  
  Non-page files   |   1  
  Static files     | 357  
  Processed images |   0  
  Aliases          |   0  
  Sitemaps         |   1  
  Cleaned          |   0
```

Comment: I think you meant `cd ... && hugo` (e.g., `&&` not `&`)

Comment: Hmm I tried that first, but it didn't work. I'll try again.

Comment: Well, `&` is _definitely_ not right.  You are basically running the `cd` in the background then starting `hugo` (in the current directory).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the path to a Hugo project with the `--source` flag (or `-s` for short)

```sh
# Short version
hugo -s /Users/me/Sites/mysite/webroot/hugosite

# Long version
hugo --source /Users/me/Sites/mysite/webroot/hugosite
```

Answer (score 0):

MadScientist is right. '&& hugo' seemed to do the trick